# Images not getting displayed in PDF (barryvdh/laravel-snappy package)

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu-18.04, laravel-snappy, knp-snappy

I am using **barryvdh/laravel-snappy** package in Laravel framework to convert html file into PDF.

It is working fine, but **images** in the PDF are not getting displayed.

Image path used in the html is like:

https://easydmc-staging2.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/ImagesSightseeing/2021/03/1PeocnxOb3gqlZmMSjwXDWwLiEfyq0a8KX5M4OOw.jpeg

Here is the link of html:

https://staging.easydmc.com/test?html=true

And the link to generated PDF is:

https://staging.easydmc.com/test?html=false

Earlier the images were working fine in the PDF. A few days back I had executed the command - sudo apt upgrade. I do not whether this is causing the problem or not.

I tried re-installing the package **barryvdh/laravel-snappy**, but no success.

Any help would be appreciated.

PHP version: 8.0

Server: Nginx

Laravel: 8.51.0

Comment: show the add, also show contents within the stackoverflow itself by using `!` before the link

Answer (score 0):

I previously had this issue, it is because of `wkhtmltopdf`. You should use storage full path instead of web url.

For example instead of using:

```
https://easydmc-staging2.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/ImagesSightseeing/2021/03/1PeocnxOb3gqlZmMSjwXDWwLiEfyq0a8KX5M4OOw.jpeg
```

use something like this:

```
/var/www/html/myproject/public/ImagesSightseeing/2021/03/1PeocnxOb3gqlZmMSjwXDWwLiEfyq0a8KX5M4OOw.jpeg
```

to get the full storage path you can use code like below:

```php
<img src="{{public_path('/ImagesSightseeing/2021/03/1PeocnxOb3gqlZmMSjwXDWwLiEfyq0a8KX5M4OOw.jpeg')}}" />
```

Comment: I could have apply your suggestion but the image path is of AWS S3.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:

First I checked whether there is an issue or not while generating the PDF using below command:

```
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 http://www.google.com test.pdf
```

I got to know below issues:

```
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_num_locks                  ] 10%
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_free
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_num
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_pop_free
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_value
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_load_error_strings
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_CTX_get_chain
QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLeay
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_num_locks
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function sk_num
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method00%
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
```

The solution on above problem was to install libssl1.0-dev:

```
apt install libssl1.0-dev
```

So my PDF link https://staging.easydmc.com/test?html=false in original question started working now.